# c# add the namespace to the existing xml node

Tags: c#, linq, kml

I have a xml file which starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" 
    xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

When I run my below code it it gives me error 'xsi' is an undeclared prefix.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(kmlFileUrl);  //throws error xsi' is an undeclared prefix

XNamespace ns = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";

xDoc.Root
.Elements(ns + "Document")
.Elements(ns + "Placemark")
.GroupBy(i => (string)i)
.SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
.Remove();
```

I researched on internet and found that this occurs due to missing of the xsi namespace declaration.
I tried with this code

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";                   
XDocument doc = new XDocument(                          
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")                          
        );
```

Expected result:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" 
    xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Since I am not able to load the file how do I add the namespace to the existing file  node such that I do not have to change my other code lines?

**Edit**

The difference is the solution there has this line

```
  XmlReader rd = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(strXmlFile), xset, context);
```

Here the StringReader taken input as string and I am using a xml file. The xml files is too long and I do not want to write extra code to first convert it in string and than do other stuff. Also please note that I am already using the XDocument xDoc variable in code to find the elements.

I was expecting someone to advise on how can I use the XDocument and also add the namespace. Hope this makes sense.

Let me know if someone wants to help and needs more inputs on this.

Comment: The party that created that xml file should fix their stuff.

Comment: Agree with rene. If you're getting this error, it means that whoever generated your input is giving you "XML", not XML. They're giving you a *string* that closely resembles XML but is, in fact, not XML. Get them to stop hand-mangling strings together and use appropriate XML tooling at their end so that they generate actual XML.

Comment: The file opens in Google Earth and shows the placemarks, its just that I am not able to load it for removing the duplicate placemark

Comment: Just wondering there has to be a way to append the namespace in existing file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638058/xsi-is-an-undeclared-prefix-using-xmldocument

Comment: I have already seen this but as you see my code has var xDoc = XDocument.Load(kmlFile); to load the file and then query on xDoc. How do I get the xDoc?

Comment: this answer can be applied to your case:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20662863/1537726

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml - no it can not unless I have a string and not a file

Comment: strXmlFile in the answer I linked you to is a file path not the content of the xml file

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml - XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strXmlFile, settings, context); yes this takes the xml file name but it return the XMLDocument and I want XDocument..because I have to run this code also xDoc.Root
.Elements(ns + "Document")
.Elements(ns + "Placemark")
.GroupBy(i => (string)i)
.SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
.Remove();

Comment: @rene The file is a valid google earth KML file in XML format. It does open up correctly in Google earth.

Comment: `var xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);` will give you the XDocument

Comment: @user1254053 first fix your xml and save it then load it with XDocument.